# Unable to fetch object using Promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm using the new Fetch API to retreive objects from an API. This is my code.

```
getUserYguid(){
  fetch(this.myapi, {
    credentials: "include",
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: null
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response.json());
    let obj = response.text();
    console.log(obj.name);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
}
```

When I call response.status, it works fine and I can see the status message as 200.
When I call response.json() or response.text(), i can see the complete object being returned.
The problem is that the next line of code doesn't work.
When I try to retrieve a property from the object, like

`console.log(obj.name);`

I get,
`undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.text()` returns a promise so you have to use `then` one more time

```
fetch(url, opts).then(function(response){
  response.text().then(function(txt){
    console.log(txt)
  })
})
```

and by the look of your `obj.name` use it seems like you want a json response...
not a text, so you need to do:

```
fetch(url, opts).then(function(response){
  response.json().then(function(obj){
    console.log(obj.name)
  })
})
```

`get` is the default method so no need to specify that... and blob is null so there is no need for that either...